# Mock class used in isinstance checks which has dynamic attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-mock

Some classes define their attributes (aka fields) at the class level (outside `__init__` or any other function). Some classes define them inside their `__init__` function or even from other functions. Some classes use both approaches.

```
class MyClass(object):
  foo = 'foo'
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.bar = 'bar'
```

The problem is, when you use `dir`, it only includes `'bar'` if you pass in an instance of the class.

```
>>> dir(MyClass)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'foo']
>>> myInstance = MyClass()
>>> dir(myInstance)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bar', 'foo']
```

(scroll to the far right to see the diff)

I have a situation where I need to avoid instantiating `MyClass` but I want to use it as the `spec` setting (to pass an `isinstance` check) in a `mock.patch` call in a unit test.

```
@mock.patch('mypackage.MyClass', spec=MyClass)
def test_thing_that_depends_on_MyClass(self, executeQueryMock):
  # uses 'thing' here, which uses MyClass.bar ...
```

Doing this causes:

> AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'bar'

This makes sense because the [mock docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html) says:

> spec: This can be either a list of strings or an existing object (a class or instance) that acts as the specification for the mock object. **If you pass in an object then a list of strings is formed by calling dir on the object (excluding unsupported magic attributes and methods). Accessing any attribute not in this list will raise an AttributeError.**

Even if I do instantiate `MyClass`, I get a different error.

```
@mock.patch('mypackage.MyClass', spec=MyClass())
def test_thing_that_depends_on_MyClass(self, executeQueryMock):
  # uses 'thing' here, which uses MyClass.bar ...
```

Causes:

> TypeError: 'NonCallableMagicMock' object is not callable

I don't really care about being strict with which functions/attributes I allow accessing of; I actually want the normal MagicMock behaviour which lets you call anything without `AttributeError`. It seems like using `spec` makes this strict even though I am just using `spec` to pass `isinstance` check.

### Question:

How do I properly mock this class which is used in `isinstance` checks and has attributes which are not defined at the class level?

Comment: Generally, it's probably best not to mock the whole class, but to just mock the methods on the class that have unwanted side-effects in testing.  Is that possible?

Comment: @mgilson Unfortunately, the 'thing' under test instantiates a new `MyClass` instance inside its function and that is what I am trying to mock out. This could likely be resolved with dependency injection but it is legacy code that I am trying to write some tests around so I have been avoiding refactoring until I have a good regression suite to rely on.

Comment: But my question is why do you _need_ to mock the whole class?  Why not just mock the parts of it that have side-effects?  Are they explicitly in `__init__` or something?  Also, you can set a `__class__` attribute on a `MagicMock` that allows it to pass `isinstance` checks, but I'm not sure how much that helps.

Comment: Yes, the part with side effects is `MyClass.__init()`.

Comment: @mgilson I ended up re-evaluating my need to mock out the entire `MyClass` class. I moved some of the side-effects out of the `__init__ function to facilitate this. Thanks for prompting me to re-think how I was going about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you just want to pass `isinstance` checks, I think the simplest solution is to write a quick wrapper to `mock.patch.object` that sets the `__class__` attribute of the returned mock.

```
def my_patch(obj, attr_name):
    fake_class = mock.MagicMock()
    fake_instance = fake_class.return_value  # calling a class returns an instance.
    fake_instance.__class__ = getattr(obj, attr_name)
    return mock.patch.object(obj, attr_name, fake_class)
```

It's used like `mock.patch.object`:

```
@my_patch(some_module, 'MyClass')
def test_something(self, fake_my_class):
    ...
```

but the fake object should pass `isinstance` checks the same way that a spec'd mock would.

Comment: I tried this solution and it seemed to work for getting past my `isinstance` checks but I ran into some other issues. This isn't how I ended up solving my problem, but I will give you the accepted answer for helping me out. Thanks!